# ServiceStack.Text: Forcing serialization of a property not decorated with DataMember attribute

Tags: c#, servicestack, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have the following class (simplified).

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ServiceResponseStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using ServiceStack to serialize objects for logging purposes, and letting `DataContractSerializer` do the rest. ServiceStack, as expected, will not serialize `Sequence` as it is not decorated with a `DataMember` attribute.

Is there a way to force ServiceStack to serialize this property?

Marc Gravell's answer to this similar question [DataContract Serialization without DataMember Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309010/datacontract-serialization-without-datamember-attribute) seems to suggest a different approach, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorating your classes with `DataContract/DataMember` attributes is **specifically** used for opting in which properties you want serialized. If you want all properties serialized **remove** all the attributes.

See this answer for other ways to [ignore properties in Servicestack serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785).

Comment: Here's the thing: I want all properties serialized for logging purposes in the service, including `Sequence`, but I don't want that property leaking in the API (clients shouldn't need to know about it), which is why it's not decorated with the `DataMember` attribute. Is that a bit clearer?

Comment: Use something else for your logging. Like I said `DataMember` attributes are **specifically** used to opt-in which properties get serialized. i.e. You're asking how to reverse the **exact behavior they're intended for**. Use something else - I can't be any clearer than this.

Comment: I understand your point. I know what I'm trying to do is weird, but having used and liked ServiceStack.Text before, I wanted to do away with manual serialization.

Comment: Doesn't need to be manual mapping, i.e. you can maintain a similar class with just the fields you want to logged and use an [Auto Mapper like ServiceStack's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) to auto populate the properties which you can then serialize for logging.