# Servicestack call giving 404 but after restart IIS it works

Tags: iis, servicestack

We have been using servicestack version 3.8.5.0 for a few years.
We noticed an occasional error where one of the web services returns 404. This service is part of an assembly where the other webs services all work.

This service has not been modified for a number of years and if we restart IIS the service works as expected.

Any ideas where to look on what might have caused the 'registration' to fail?

**Edit:**
Just found that this issue happens consistently on rebooting the server. So if I restarted IIS a number of times and I do not see the issue. However on rebooting our server, the issue appeared.

Comment: No idea. Do you still have same problem using latest v3 release? https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3

Comment: It is so hard to reproduce so not sure if moving up would help. Is there any logging that could help identify the issue?

Comment: You can try to call your service appending "?debug=requestinfo" (without quotes) at the end of your service request.

Comment: If I am getting 404 so in effect IIS cannot find the service, will appending debug just return me the same 404?

Comment: In fact, if the 404 is thrown by IIS then ServiceStack cannot intercept it.

Comment: Maybe @mythz can help here

Comment: Okay, I noticed all the other DTOs in the .cs file have [DataContract(Name = "Server", Namespace = "")] whereas this DTO had a different name ([DataContract(Name = "PingServer", Namespace = "")]). I changed it and the error has not occurred on 10 reboots. Have I just hidden the issue as I do not think this is the fix?

Comment: I don't know since I never used DataContract. Do you really need it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971117/servicestack-text-forcing-serialization-of-a-property-not-decorated-with-datame

Comment: What version of IIS is it running on? can you share the `web.config` file?